# Express middleware next issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I am not clear on how to sequentially call Express middleware. I would like to have the next middleware in line only happen once the previous one is done. I thought that I had to call next() for it to happen but evidently that is not the case.

```
mongoose.connect(app.set("db-uri"));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 if(1 !== mongoose.connection.readyState) {
    console.log('Database not connected');
    res.render("system/maintenance", {
      status: 500
    });
  } else {
    return next();
  }
});


// This middleware does not wait for the previous next(). It just tries to connect before actually.
app.use(express.session({
  secret: settings.sessionSecret,
  maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
  store: new MongoStore({ mongoose_connection: mongoose.connections[0], auto_reconnect: true })
}));
```

**Edit:** Updated code to only connect Mongoose on start and check state in middleware

Comment: You shouldn't connect with mongoose on every request. Also the app.use() calls are all called when the server starts, while your connection does not occur until the first request.

Comment: Suggestions on how to handle mongoose failures within express and preventing subsequent connections such as sessions?

Answer (score 1):

I admit this isn't a very complete answer, not to mention tested, but the gist of it should work.

First of all, connect to the database when starting the app, eg not in a middleware. Just put the `moongoose.connect` stuff outside of `app.use` somewhere (see any mongoose+express example, like [this one](https://gist.github.com/fwielstra/1025038)).

Second, I'd use a "flag" that keeps track of whether or not mongoose has disconnected.

```
var mongooseIsConnected = false;

mongoose.on('open', function () {
  mongooseIsConnected = true;
});

mongoose.on('error', function () {
  mongooseIsConnected = false;
});
```

*Note that this is very much a guess.* I don't know if the error event fires only on connection failure and likewise I don't know if "open" fires when reconnecting. If you find that in some docs please tell me and I'll update this answer.

Finally it's straight forward to put a middleware – before any other middlewares using the database – which checks if the flag is true or false and either passes the request on or renders an error.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if(mongooseIsConnected) {
    next();
  }
  else {
    res.status(500);
    res.render('errorView');
    // Or you could call next(new Error('The database is broken')); and handle 
    // the error in a central express errorHandler
  }
});

// app.use(express.session etc here...
```

### Update, a solution to not use the mongoose connection before it's open:

```
mongoose.connect('uri...', configureApp);

function configureApp () {
  app.use(express.session({
    secret: settings.sessionSecret,
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    store: new MongoStore({ mongoose_connection: mongoose.connections[0], auto_reconnect: true })
  }));

  // The other middleware and app.listen etc
}
```

This should ensure the connection is made before the middlewares are defined. However when digging though my own code I see that I simply let MongoStore create a new connection. That's probably easier.

Comment: Problem is that the next middleware starts before this one. I have something like this now where I check for a live connection `if(1 !== mongoose.connection.readyState)` and either next() or render a 500. But the next middleware still errors and crashes. Weird.

Comment: I've updated my code to what I have now. MongoStore still crashes the app.

Comment: Ah now I see, I think you mean where you use `mongoose.connections[0]`. That code isn't in a middleware but run on init. What you could do is put all of the middleware declarations inside mongoose.on('open', ...)

Comment: How? This is mongo store - express/connect middleware. I've tried the auto_reconnect option but doesn't seem to do squat.

Comment: I updated my answer with what i meant. Not sure if I understood your problem completely though.

Comment: That would not work in my scenario - all my app.use are done in a group under app.configure(). But I think my answer below does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Ok this seems to work. Open to comments on issues here.

```
var store;
mongoose.connect(app.set("db-uri"));
mongoose.connection.on("connect", function(err) {
  // Create session store connection
  store = new MongoStore({ mongoose_connection: mongoose.connections[0], auto_reconnect: true });
});


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(1 !== mongoose.connection.readyState) {
    console.log('Database not connected');
    // Try a restart else it will stay down even when db comes back up
    mongoose.connect(app.set("db-uri"));
    res.render("system/maintenance", {
      status: 500
    });
  } else {
    return next();
  }
});

app.use(express.session({
  secret: settings.sessionSecret,
  maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
  store: store
}));
```

Appears to work - I was concerned session store would not come back up but I think it works.